# Set of surjective bounded linear operator between two Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I've to prove that the set of all subjective bounded linear operator is a closed subset of B(X, Y).

I tried with a sequence $T_n$ of surjective bounded maps, suppose it converges to some T $\in$ B(X, Y).

I've to show now T is surjective and bounded.

Let y $\in$ Y, for each $T_n$ there exists $x_n \in$ X such that $T_n(x_n)=y$.

Can someone help me how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Take $Y$ to be the scalar field. Let $f$ be any non-zero continuous linear functional on $X$ And $f_n=\frac  f n$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in operator norm and each $f_n$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh thanks, What about openness of this subset?